# Nginx -> Apache 2 authentication -> return to Nginix

Tags: authentication, nginx, apache2, kerberos

We have a nginx and an apache2 server.

Apache2 is configured to manage Kerberos (Active Directory) authentication.

We have a website managed by nginx with a reserved area.

I would know if this is possible:

1. the user goes to main site managed by nginx
2. from main site, there is a link to "/login" mapped to apache2:

```
   location /login/ {
       proxy_pass http://apache2server/testlogin;
   }
```

3. when the login is successful, apache2 is configured to go to another nginx webpage, using proxypass too:

```
        ProxyPass /testlogin http://nginxserver/logindone.php
        ProxyPassReverse /testlogin http://nginxserver/logindone.php
```

I wonder if this is the right solution to the problem.

Comment: What https module are you using for the Kerberos Auth? What the configuration looks like? Do you really just want to proxy / forward the user to just another site or do you need to work with the active session and keep it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can implement an external authentication to your *NGiNX* website is using `auth_request` directive.

Basically, you can protect any request doing a subrequest to any external web server. The subrequest must return HTTP code 2XX to allow proceeding to the content, and any other HTTP code returned will deny access.

To accomplish that, be sure you've *NGiNX* with `auth_request` enabled (compiled with `--with-http_auth_request_module`). To check that, use the following command at shell:

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | grep "http_auth_request_module"
```

Add the `auth_request` directive to the location you want to protect, specifying an internal location where the authorization subrequest will be forwarded to, using:

```
location /system/ {
    auth_request /auth;
    #...
}
```

So, when a request is made to */system/* location, the system will create a subrequest to */auth* location. Now we need to create the internal */auth* location. We can use the following example below:

```
location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://my.app.webserver/auth_endpoint;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    #...
}
```

Here, we created the */auth* internal location. We used the `internal` directive to disable external *NGiNX* access (any external request to */auth* will not be processed by this location). Also, we removed the request body content and set the request length to zero, removing any original request variable. We do a subrequest to *http://my.app.webserver/auth_endpoint* passing all requested cookies, so your backend application could determine if user has access or not.

If you need to know the original requested URI, you can add it on an extra HTTP header at subrequest adding:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
```

You can learn more about *NGiNX* `auth_request` directive [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/).

Comment: Interesting. Can the external authentication return to NGINX the username of the logged user? In my apache2 config I'm using `RequestHeader set Remote-User expr=%{REMOTE_USER}` to pass the username

Comment: I have a problem. When I implemented your solution, going from Nginx to Apache2, the last one doesn't show the authorization request window.